# Problems with Bonjour WiFi on iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, wifi, bonjour

I have an app that uses Bonjour Wifi to connect to my iPhone app from an iMac. I also have 2 SSIDs. However the iOS app will work for some hours and then cannot connect to one SSID. If I toggle to the other SSID I can connect again for a few more hours before I have to repeat the process. I also have an iPad and it behaves the same way.
Has anyone an idea of why this is happening.

Comment: I could be wrong but I've never heard fo Bonjour Wifi and a quick Google doesn't show any specific results, what do you mean by this?

Comment: Apple uses Bonjour to establish WiFi connections. But your question got me to do a bit more googling and I found this: https://appletoolbox.com/2017/02/wifi-dropping-not-available-ios-update-fix/ which confirms my suspicion that it is an Apple bug and caused by the most recent version of iOS in June. One other solution I just discovered is to turn WiFi off and back on.

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses Bonjour to establish WiFi connections. It is an Apple bug and caused by the most recent version of iOS in June. One workaround is to turn WiFi off and back on.